# How can I prevent HDMI 5V (55mA) from entering a circuit?

Tags: hdmi

I have a circuit which uses a camera with HDMI out and a HDMI to AV converter, as well as some other 5V components. 
[image]

The issue I have is that when the main 5V power source is off, but the camera is on, the 5V (55mA) used for device ID on the HDMI cable enters the circuit via the HDMI to AV converter power supply, and causes issues since all the 5V components are now underpowered.

Is there a way to prevent the 5V backfeeding to the main circuit in this situation? Is that what a Schottky diode is for? Any advice on specs required would be much appreciated. Other relavant info, given that only 5.1V is supplied from tha main power source (so voltage drop may be a consideration). All the components are "off the shelf" so not readily modified, but parts/components can be added into the circuit at any of the power/cable junctions.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Um, the solution here is fixing your power supply: If a current draw of 55 mA means your other components are undersupplied, there's not something wrong with your HDMI, but with your 5V supply.

Comment: Colourful spaghetti!

Comment: Hi Marcus, the problem is when the 5V power source is OFF, but the camera is running off batteries. So the 5V from the HDMI device ID enters the circuit and causes erraatic behaviour in the other 5V devices. Thanks

Comment: The main issue seems to be with improper design of the HDMI to AV converter apparently cross-connecting power domains.  Questions about the *usage* of products are not really on topic here, as we don't have enough information to know how they would behave if used in a different way than intended... or in this case, even if used *as* intended.

Comment: Is there any reason at all to run the camera with the rest of the system turned off? If turning the camera off is hard to implement, why don't you just remove the battery?

Comment: The HDMI to AV converter is not compliant with HDMI specification or simply faulty. Is that enough a reason to return it?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all the suggestions. On the advice of some of the replies, I checked another brand of the same type of device, and it seems the newer ones are HDMI compliant, since there is no 5V "backfeeding" to the main power source. The original models were cheap $5 versions on eBay, the HDMI compliant versions are $70(!!!)

This has fixed my problem, thanks